# edge contraction and planar Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and $e\in E$ be any edge. Let denote $G/e$ denote the graph obtained by contracting the edge e.

> > Proof: If G is a planar graph, so is G/e

While this is intuitively clear, I don't know how to formulate it.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Removing a vertex just merges two faces, so if the graph was planar it remains planar.

Comment: This follows from Wagner's theorem pretty easily, but I'm assuming you don't want to use that? "A finite graph is planar if and only if it does not have K5 or K3,3 as a minor."

Comment: @N8tron that's Kuratowski's theorem, right? And this fact is used in its proof, so that's circular reasoning. BTW, it seems they're [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem) theorems.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes that's why I said "I'm assuming you don't want to use that"